# Removing this left-recursive way to define a SELECT statement

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to parse the following `SELECT` statement:

```
select 1 union all (select 1) union all (with cte as (select 1) select 1 from tbl limit 1) 
union all select 1 union all (select 1 limit 1)
```

And this is the grammar I currently have (at least to be able to reproduce the issue):

```
parser grammar DBParser;
options { tokenVocab = DBLexer;}

root
    : selectStatement SEMI? EOF
    ;

selectStatement
    : withClause?
    ( selectClause | OPEN_PAREN selectStatement CLOSE_PAREN | selectStatement setOperand selectStatement)
    orderLimitClause?
    ;

withClause
    : WITH IDENTIFIER AS OPEN_PAREN selectClause CLOSE_PAREN
    ;

orderLimitClause
    : LIMIT NUMBER
    ;

selectClause
    : SELECT NUMBER ( FROM IDENTIFIER )?
    ;

setOperand
    : UNION ALL?
    ;
```

```
lexer grammar DBLexer;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }
SELECT              :           'SELECT';                   // SELECT *...
LIMIT               :           'LIMIT';                    // ORDER BY x LIMIT 20
ALL                 :           'ALL';                      // SELECT ALL vs. SELECT DISTINCT; WHERE ALL (...); UNION ALL...
UNION               :           'UNION';                    // Set operation
FROM                :           'FROM';                    // Set operation
AS                  :           'AS';                      // Set operation
WITH                :           'WITH';                    // Set operation

SEMI                :           ';';                        // Statement terminator
OPEN_PAREN          :           '(';                        // Function calls, object declarations
CLOSE_PAREN         :           ')';

NUMBER
     : [0-9]+
    ;
IDENTIFIER
    : [A-Z_] [A-Z_0-9]*
    ;
WHITESPACE
    : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
    ;
```

The issue is the `selectStatement` which refers to itself without a possible alternation:

```
selectStatement
    : withClause?
    ( selectClause | OPEN_PAREN selectStatement <-- here 
    ;
```

What might be a possible way to resolve this? Note that the main part of the SQL grammar is from [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax), which gives a nice clean/colored representation of things (of course I have simiplified the `select` clause as well as everything else):

[image]

Comment: might help to dig through a standard grammar e.g. https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/postgresql/PostgreSQLParser.g4

Comment: @GavinHaynes yea I've been using that as a starting place actually, my favorite and the cleanest I think that I've seen is: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLParser.g4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a higher level rule. Maybe this:

```
selectStatement
   : simpleSelectStatement (setOperand selectStatement)?

simpleSelectStatement
    : withClause?
    ( selectClause | OPEN_PAREN selectStatement CLOSE_PAREN)
    orderLimitClause?
    ;
```

Comment: actually the Postgres one is the one I'm using as a reference. I think the above is such a hack-ish way to deal with it though. Then you get almost two sets of statements for "this_with_parens" vs. "this_no_parens" -- I actually liked your first solution better. Was it able to work on the sample input? -- I'd suggest changing your answer back to the previous!

Comment: I'm not sure if it would always work, but typically the limitation on left recursion can add a bit of complexity.

Comment: is there a general approach you use to remove left-recursion? For example, how did you know to do the above?

Comment: looks good to me. You can use this screenshot if you want: https://gyazo.com/8779564727e867b66a959c1ac152802e, https://gyazo.com/6e50e993a8b198f726cccc7a16a6b0a3

Comment: You can look up `Elimination of Left Recursion` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7iGUr2W5N8

Comment: In our case a direct application of https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-left-recursion-and-how-it-is-eliminated#:~:text=A%20Grammar%20G%20(V%2C%20T,A%20%E2%86%92%20A%20%CE%B1%20%7C%CE%B2.&text=Left%20Recursion%20can%20be%20eliminated,non%2Dterminal%20A%20such%20that. would take us from what we had originally:

`selectStmt: selectStmt (setOp selectStmt) | simpleSelectStmt`

to

`selectStmt: simpleSelectStmt selectStmt'` and 
`selectStmt': (setOp selectStmt) | empty`

which simplifies to

`selectStmt: simpleSelectStmt (setOp selectStmt)?`

Comment: you mentioned you `had this originally` -- `selectStmt: selectStmt (setOp selectStmt) | simpleSelectStmt`. How did you create that part in the first place though? I did a cmd-f and the `simpleSelect` is only in your answer and comments so seeing how you came up with that in the first place.

Comment: I just rearranged some things you had. If you set `simpleSelectStatement: withClause?
    ( selectClause | OPEN_PAREN selectStatement CLOSE_PAREN` then your original grammar would be equal to `selectStatement : simpleSelectStatement | selectStatement (setOperand selectStatement) orderLimitClause? ;` which is equal to `selectStatement : selectStatement (setOperand selectStatement) orderLimitClause | simpleSelectStatement ? ;` which matches the pattern given for left recursion elimination in tutorialspoint.com