# Disambiguate a SQL set operation (UNION|INTERSECT|EXCEPT)

Tags: sql, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am working on a SQL grammar similar (at a high level) to BigQuery, which has the following [top-level syntax structure](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#set_clause):

```
query_statement:
    query_expr

query_expr:
    [ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] { non_recursive_cte | recursive_cte }[, ...] ]
    { select | ( query_expr ) | set_operation }
    [ ORDER BY expression [{ ASC | DESC }] [, ...] ]
    [ LIMIT count [ OFFSET skip_rows ] ]

set_operation:
  query_expr set_operator query_expr

set_operator:
  UNION { ALL | DISTINCT } | INTERSECT DISTINCT | EXCEPT DISTINCT
```

Here is the simplest grammar example I can think of to show an example of the above clauses (Note I have have modified the statement a bit to remove left recursion outlined here: [Removing this left-recursive way to define a SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73410436/removing-this-left-recursive-way-to-define-a-select-statement)).

```
grammar DBParser;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }
statement: query_statement EOF;

query_statement
   : query_expr (set_operator query_statement)?
   ;

query_expr:
    with_clause?
    ( select_clause | '(' query_statement ')')
    order_clause?
    limit_clause?;


with_clause: 'WITH tbl AS (SELECT 1)';
select_clause: 'SELECT 1';
order_clause: 'ORDER BY 1';
limit_clause: 'LIMIT 1';
set_operator: 'UNION' | 'INTERSECT' | 'EXCEPT';

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

And with the sample statement `SELECT 1 UNION select 1 union (WITH tbl AS (SELECT 1) SELECT 1) limit 1`, I get the following parse tree:

[image]

However, I believe this grammar may be ambiguous (also pointed out in the answer from here: [How to simplify this left-recursive rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73423046/how-to-simplify-this-left-recursive-rule/73423446#73423446)). I'm not sure exactly why, but my thinking is that there are possibly several ways to interpret this:

```
SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 1 LIMIT 1

SELECT 1 UNION (SELECT 1 LIMIT 1)
(SELECT 1 UNION (SELECT 1) LIMIT 1)
```

Is the grammar I have of the `set` operation ambiguous (Is BigQuery's definition also ambiguous?) And if so, how could that be properly solved with antlr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the grammar might, technically be ambiguous (i.e. there are multiple ways the parser rules *could* be applied to build different parse trees), it's not pragmatically ambiguous for ANTLR.

As the parser recursively invokes sub-rules, that sub-rule will attempt to match as much of the input stream as possible before retuning to the parent rule.  As a result, it will always be interpreted as

```
SELECT 1 UNION (SELECT 1 LIMIT 1)
```

Perhaps a better term for this is that ANTLR's handling will be deterministic despite there being another possible interpretation of the rule application (i.e. an ambiguity)

re: associativity of you `set_operator`, with the following change to your grammar:

```
query_statement
   : query_expr # simplequery
   | query_statement set_operator query_statement # setQuery
   ;
```

You get this parse tree:

[image]

You can make the `set_operator` right-associative like so:

```
query_statement
   : query_expr # simplequery
   | <assoc=right> query_statement set_operator query_statement # setQuery
   ;
```

And get this parse tree:
[image]

This has no effect on which `SELECT` the `LIMIT` binds to.

Off hand, I'm not sure how you would get

```
SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 1 LIMIT 1
```

interpreted as:

```
(SELECT 1 UNION (SELECT 1) LIMIT 1)
```

(it also seems as though it would be a most unintuitive interpretation of the input, but that's just my opinion)

Comment: ah, so it becomes `right-associative`, correct? How would it be made left-associative, which is what I need for the `UNION|INTERSECT|EXCEPT` operand?

Comment: No, ANTLR is always left-associative unless you tell it otherwise with `<assoc=right>`.  This isn't about associativity but about recursive descent parsing. I'll amend the answer to show how associativity could play into the set_operator, but it won't affect which SELECT the "LIMIT 1" binds to.